# How to make field text_ws case insensitive

Tags: c#, apache, solr

I am using text_ws field in Solr, example : when i search for FOOTBALL it do not show any result when Solr contains data like football.

when i search for FOOTBALL, football or FooTBall, It should give result related to football, I want to use text_ws field with case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `text_ws` field definition only uses the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` tokenizer, you can see this via

```
$ curl localhost:8983/solr/your-core/schema/fieldtypes/text_ws

{
  "responseHeader":{
   ...
  "fieldType":{
    "name":"text_ws",
    "class":"solr.TextField",
    "positionIncrementGap":"100",
    "analyzer":{
      "tokenizer":{
        "class":"solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"}}}}
```

If you want case insensitive searches you will need to modify the definition of this field type to include something like the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` as the `text_general` field does:

```
$ curl localhost:8983/solr/your-core/schema/fieldtypes/text_general

{
  "responseHeader":{
  ...
  "fieldType":{
    "name":"text_general",
    "class":"solr.TextField",
    "positionIncrementGap":"100",
    "multiValued":true,
    "indexAnalyzer":{
      "tokenizer":{
        "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"},
      "filters":[{
          "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
          "words":"stopwords.txt",
          "ignoreCase":"true"},
        {
          "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"}]},
   ...
```

Or perhaps you could copy the value of your `text_ws` field to a `text_general` field and run your case insensitive searches against the text_general field.